# why listbox selected index changed is not firing?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have written a `javascript` method to `sortlistbox` items and it works well in a sense that the item that I type in text box gets highlighted.

But when I click on the highlighted item it dosen't gets selected. Why?
The `selectedIndexchanged` is not working.

Here is my javascript code:

```
 function SearchList() {
         var l = document.getElementById("<%= LBox.ClientID %>");
         var tb = document.getElementById("<%= txtDepartments.ClientID %>");
         if (tb.value == "") {
             ClearSelection(l);
         }
         else {
             for (var i = 0; i < l.options.length; i++) {
                 if (l.options[i].value.toLowerCase().match(tb.value.toLowerCase())) {
                     l.options[i].selected = true;

                     return false;
                 }
                 else {
                     ClearSelection(l);
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     function ClearSelection(l) {
         l.selectedIndex = -1;
     }
```

Comment: How do you call this function - show that code?

Comment: have you tried used JQuery to fire the Change event of dropdown instead of onkeyup? I can post you an example...

Comment: no i have not tried it yet. yes you can postit. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do this, then call your function inside, *you need to reference jquery library*  :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {    
            $('#' + '<%= DropdownName.ClientID %>').change(function() {
                      // Call function here...
               });

            });
```

Comment: which version of jquery library.

Comment: latest should be fine.